# Address of strcuture member variable changed when passed by reference

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, c++11

I encountered a problem when debugging my model (written in C++) in Eclipse CDT. The problem is that when I pass a structure variable, who contains various member variables such as string or vector, to a function by reference, the value of certain member variables are not updated in the scope of that function. More details are provided as below:

```
struct ModelConfig {
//... here are some other variables and constructors 

vector<int> crop_list;

string path_to_input;

//....
};
```

Say now I start debugging in GDB, and here is the first function call  :

```
void modelMain::setupModel( const ModelConfig & sim_setting ){
    //... some operations to configure the model using 'sim_setting'

    /* 1.3 - Initialize the land */

    Set_Environment(k_farm_land, sim_setting); 
      // breakpoint here, printing out the value of 'sim_etting' shows  'sim_setting.path_to_input = "data/"' ; Then I enter into 'Set_Environment' function ...

    //...
}

void Set_Environment(vector<Soil> & farm_land, const ModelConfig & sim_setting) {
int EXP_ID = sim_setting.EXP_ID;

string strTmp_a;

strTmp_a = sim_setting.path_to_input + "soil/parameters.txt"; // Problem is here: the GDB shows here that sim_setting.path_to_input = " ". I am expecting strTmp_a = "data/soil/parameters.txt" which now is "soil/parameters.txt" ;


//... operations for reading data
}
```

The `sim_setting.path_to_input` variable should hold the string value named `data/`, which is correct during the call in `setupModel(...)`, but the value is lost (or the address is changed actually) during the call in `Set_Environment(...)`...

When using the GDB debug in Eclipse to trace the address of the variables, I notice that the address of `sim_setting` seems correct in both `setupModel` and `Set_Environment`, but the member variable of `path_to_input` and `crop_list` changed into other place, which cause the lost of data. The value of `crop_list` is created using `.push_back()`.

I did not get the point since I am passing the variable by reference. The only thing that I can imagine is due to the value assignment of string and vector. Anyone have theory for this ? Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "certain member variables are not updated" ? Is it the assignment to `strTmp_a` that is causing you problems?

Comment: @tobi303 thx for the prompt reply ! In the function call of 'setupModel", "sim_setting.path_to_input = "data/" ' which is correct. But when entering to the next function "Set_Environment()", "sim_setting.path_to_input = " " ', which causes the "strTmp_a" being assigned with a wrong path string.

Comment: @LiYu Did you overload the + operator ?

Comment: Since you are passing sim_setting as a const reference, it should not allow you to change sim_setting.path_to_input .

Comment: @brianbeuning but I don't think that I am reassigning the value of `sim_setting.path_to_input`, right ? I am only extracting the value from `sim_setting` and assign it to a different variable

Comment: @Blacktempel: `std::string::operator+` doesn't assign to anything. It creates a new string which is a concatenation of its left and right operands. And it has always had this ability, even before C++11. It doesn't matter if one or both of its operands are const, since it doesn't modify either of them.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thank you for the clarification ! I add some extra information here to better figure out the problem. In `setupModel`, the address of `sim_setting.path_to_input` is `0x631c58`, while the address becomes `0x634c80` in `Set_Environment`.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have shown which would exhibit the behavior you describe. The problem is somewhere in the code which you haven't shown. If you want help debugging your code, you will need to produce an MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please close this question, because the problem seems not reproducible. Now it works ~!

Comment: @BenjaminLindley There is no `std::string::operator+`. There is a `std::operator+` overloaded for `std::string`, but no operator in the class itself.

Comment: @Blacktempel: That's true, but the distinction is irrelevant for the point I was making.